# Mybatis foreach mapper item exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I am using `foreach` for `SELECT IN` clause.

Item has not been found by mapper.

Here is part of exception.

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found. Available parameters are [ids, param1]] with root cause

org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found. Available parameters are [ids, param1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$ParamMap.get(MapperMethod.java:212) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.MapWrapper.get(MapWrapper.java:45) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.createCacheKey(BaseExecutor.java:219) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.createCacheKey(CachingExecutor.java:146) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:88) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:145) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Param ids is found, but also param1 that does not exist.

Below is sql used in `@Select` annotation.

```xml
select a.* from ACTOR
<if test="ids != null and ids.size > 0">
    where a.ID in 
    <foreach collection="ids" item="id" separator="," close=")" open="(">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
</if>
```

Interface method is defined as

```java
public List<Actor> listByIds(@Param("ids")List<Long> ids);
```

I am already using `foreach` on other places and other sql queries, this is the only one making issue.

Comment: I don't see any problem. Check if there is any extra space or control character in the `item` attribute value.

Comment: @ave I do not see problem either, but I am suspecting some weird bug. No spaces, no control characters, which is weird by itself.

Comment: If you could share a small project on GitHub that reproduces the issue, I would take a look when I have time. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some project templates.

Comment: it is some formatter issue. It removed `script` tags from sql query in annotation for some reason. Thank you for help. @ave

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Happy to know the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select annotation MUST include `script` tag if e.g. `foreach` is going to be used, as in example below.

```java
@Select("""
<script>
select a.* from ACTOR
<if test="ids != null and ids.size > 0">
    where a.ID in 
    <foreach collection="ids" item="id" separator="," close=")" open="(">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
</if>
</script>
        """)
public List<Actor> listByIds(@Param("ids")List<Long> ids);
```

Otherwise, parameter mapper will try to find `id` param in function signature instead of foreach, because it does not know it is script.